# How was the notion of the metacenter of a floating body discovered?

Tags: mathematics, physics

Does anybody knows how this important notion of hydrostatics was discovered?

I have read that it is about someone walking up and down the mountains of Latin America trying to disprove Cartesian geometry. But I can't remember where I have read that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In  1727  the  Parisian  Royal  Academy  of  Sciences  held  a  prize  contest  on  the  optimal placement  of  masts  in  a  sailing  ship. Bouguer and 20-year old Euler, then a student of Johann Bernoulli, submitted solutions. The  optimal  placement  of the sail is directly related to the heel angle of the ship where the heeling  moment  and the  restoring moment are equal. This prompted the investigations of ship's stability that led to the introduction of the metacenter.

Bouguer  subsequently participated  in an  expedition  to  the Andes  in  Peru,  today  Ecuador,  for  geodesic  measurements  near  the  equator  from  1735  to 1744, where he  worked  on  his  treatise  Traité  du Navire on ship  hydrostatics, published  in  1746 after  his  return  to France. However, according to Nowacki, he likely started working on ship's stability already in 1732, when he tested the 18-gun frigate Gazelle in Le Havre. Euler worked on the same subject in St. Petersburg from 1737 to 1741, and summarized it in  Scientia Navalis published after a delay in 1749.

For infinitesimal angles  of  heel,  Bouguer  introduced  the  metacenter    as  the point of intersection of two infinitesimally neighboring buoyancy directions, that is directions passing through the centers of buoyancy, the centers  of  gravity  of  the  displaced  water (see his diagram below, g is the metacenter).   Generally, the  metacenter  is the center of curvature of the curve traced by the centers of buoyancy as the  ship  heels  continuously. The significance of it is that the ship is stable when the center of its gravity is below the metacenter. Bouguer  constructed  the  metacenter  numerically by using the trapezoidal rule.

Euler gave an equivalent formulation in terms of moments, without introducing the metacenter explicitly. But Euler's book was written in Latin, lacked worked out examples, and remained almost unknown to shipbuilders, while Bouguer's treatise became a blueprint for standard texts.

See [Historical Roots of the Theory of Hydrostatic Stability of Ships by Nowicki](http://www.kayakdesign.org/stabilitet/Paper01.pdf), where the following diagram from Bouguer's Traité is reproduced.

[image: Bouguer Metacenter]